# Applying ABD: mentioning defense date and thesis committee, but still waiting on a publication

Tags: faculty-application, all-but-dissertation

The job description (UK) says I need a doctorate.
I have a paper under review that I think has a 90% chance of acceptance based on the reviews.
If my paper is accepted, I'll be able to graduate before the start date.
If it's not, I may have to withdraw my candidacy (this would be before the interview date).

I want to form my thesis committee and set a date for the defense to reassure them, in my application, that I will be graduating before the start date.  On the other hand, there's still something like a 10% chance that I might not be able to, although I suspect I might be allowed to graduate without this publication if I had the job offer in hand and it was all that was holding me back.

(How) can I get what I want here without burning any bridges?

Comment: Get what?       Comment is minimum length.

Comment: You call them (the job guys) and tell them your situation and ask. Rarely does "something is written in some rules) (like the doctorate here) really somehing unmoveable. (But this depends on your location, so please add a location tag.)

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I want to form a committee and set a date for my defense, despite my adviser having said that I need this article to be published in order to graduate.  And I want to ensure that in the unlikely event that I can't graduate in time, I'll be able to exit the application process gracefully (e.g. so that I could reapply at a later date).

Comment: So you have two different questions.  Please only have one question per post.  I suggest not worrying too much about a job you have not been offered.

Comment: Apply for the job and if you get an offer, you can easily negotiate a later start date. This is common (at least in my field).

Comment: I agree with @astronat - most folks who hire fresh PhDs understand that dates are, well, highly subject to change. It is just the nature of those last few months of scramble. I, personally, had a ~3 month delay to the start of my post-doc because things did not go as smoothly as I had optimistically suspected. And the institute completely understood, as I have for all my post-doc hires.